# Inserting a foreign key into a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep getting an error when I try to insert a new row into my `CUSTOMER_BILLING` table that **"string or binary data would be truncated."** The foreign key is `CUST_ID` and it comes from the `CUSTOMER` table

**CUSTOMER table :**

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES ('1234','Ragnar','Lothbrok','457 Raiding Rd','Kattegat','PA','19335','4845555555', 'rlothbrok@gmail.com)
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES ('1235','Daenerys','Stormborn','567 Targaryen Way','Westoros','CA','90001','3026781234','bendtheknee@gmail.com')
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES ('1236','Jon','Snow','123 Winterfell Ave','Castle Black','CA', '90002','6109258787', 'winteriscoming@gmail.com')

CUSTOMER_BILLING table
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_BILLING
VALUES ('123456',(SELECT CUST_ID FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUST_ID='1234'),'15-May-2017','14-Jun-2017','01-Jun-2017','567890','457 Raiding Rd','Kattegat','PA','19335','4845555555','rlothbrok@gmail.com')
```

I'm not sure if the foreign key is the problem. Any help would be great. I'm using Microsoft SQL 2017.

Comment: It is not related to foreign key. you are trying to insert string value which exceeds the column length..Provide table structure for more help

Comment: To me the error sounds like your string being inserted is perhaps being truncated due to there not being enough space in the column.  Please show us the table definitions.

Comment: You're missing a closing quote on the first email address and it's being inserted as "rlothbrok@gmail.com)
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES ("

Comment: Also you can use `'1234'` instead of `(SELECT CUST_ID FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUST_ID='1234')`

Comment: Note TYPO error questions don't aggregates value for the site and are likely to be deleted. And `(SELECT CUST_ID FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUST_ID='1234')` really?!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES ('1234','Ragnar','Lothbrok','457 Raiding Rd','Kattegat','PA','19335','4845555555', 'rlothbrok@gmail.com')
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES ('1235','Daenerys','Stormborn','567 Targaryen Way','Westoros','CA','90001','3026781234','bendtheknee@gmail.com')
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES ('1236','Jon','Snow','123 Winterfell Ave','Castle Black','CA', '90002','6109258787', 'winteriscoming@gmail.com')

CUSTOMER_BILLING table
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_BILLING
VALUES ('123456','1234','15-May-2017','14-Jun-2017','01-Jun-2017','567890','457 Raiding Rd','Kattegat','PA','19335','4845555555','rlothbrok@gmail.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the issue derives from your embedded `SELECT` inside the `VALUES` clause of append query and especially since this subquery returns more than one record.

Consider using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` append query where *CUST_ID* is retrieved and all other values are scalars. Do be aware though that this will append more than 1 record. If that is not intended, use `DISTINCT`.

Moreover, to avoid any column confusion which  can conflict with data types, consider explicitly declaring columns in `INSERT INTO` instead of relying on column position by omitting columns.

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_BILLING (VarcharCol, VarcharCol, DateCol, DateCol, DateCol, 
                              VarcharCol, VarcharCol, VarcharCol, VarcharCol, 
                              VarcharCol, VarcharCol, VarcharCol)
SELECT '123456', CUST_ID, '15-May-2017', '14-Jun-2017', '01-Jun-2017', 
       '567890', '457 Raiding Rd', 'Kattegat', 'PA', '19335', 
       '4845555555', 'rlothbrok@gmail.com'
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE CUST_ID = '1234'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the column lengths of each column in customer_billing? It looks like one of them is too short.